# Ruby/Rails App Testing - Simulating Http services/responses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, testing

I am unit testing a rails app and there are some external Http services that are being invoked in these tests. But instead of invoking these live Http services in these tests I want some kind of Http simulator.

I remember there is a rails gem for this purpose but cant seem to recollect the name for it. Anyone know here?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for [vcr](https://github.com/myronmarston/vcr), which allows you to record HTTP requests and then replay them in your tests. Check out [the github page](https://github.com/myronmarston/vcr) for documentation and usage examples.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in http://fakeweb.rubyforge.org/.

I absolutely love it. Hope you will, too.

Comment: this is not a testing helper?!